# Get Parent of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I want to reference the Object which contains an ObservableCollection by deducing it from the collection only. How can this be done in C#?

Example

```
public class Order: INotifyPropertyChanged
{   

    public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}  

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsA {get; set;}

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsB {get; set;}

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsC {get; set;}

 }
```

Reference in Code

```
private void ItemsChanged(ObservableCollection<Item> items)
{
    Order newOrder = items.Parent(); // <-- How can this be done?

    if (newOrder.OrderDate <= new DateTime (2016, 6, 30)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: More than one object can hold a reference to a single instance of your `ObservableCollection<T>`. How would you like to select the correct 'parent'? To complicate matters, object references are not arranged as a tree - there is no concept of _parent_ in the language. References can be circular, an object can reference itself and 2 objects can reference each other. It is best to be _explicit_ about what you want the language to do. Sancho Panza's answer is great.

Comment: Thanks. I think you got me on the right track, because I was thinking that there must always be one Order Object which would make it easy to provide something like a GetParent() Method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about extending ObservableCollection??

```
public ChildObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private Order parent { get;set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Order: INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    public Order()
    {
       ItemsA = new ChildOberservableCollection<Item>();
       ItemsA.parent = this;
       ...
    }

    public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}  

    public ChildObservableCollection<Item> ItemsA {get; set;}

    public ChildObservableCollection<Item> ItemsB {get; set;}

    public ChildObservableCollection<Item> ItemsC {get; set;}

}
```

reference in code:

```
private void ItemsChanged(ChildObservableCollection<Item> items)
{
    Order newOrder = items.parent; // done!

    if (newOrder.OrderDate <= new DateTime (2016, 6, 30)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of usage in context of the Question?

Comment: Thank, thats very nice!

Comment: This is great. The only thing I'd change is to add a constructor for `ChildObservableCollection` that takes the parent in as a parameter, so that you can't construct one without specifying a parent.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a linq approach, which can also be helpful in some cases:

```
(from order in orders
from itemA in order.ItemsA
select new { o = order.Date, i = itemA.ID }).ToList())
```